# Swift 2 - Send POST request failed - (lldb)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, post, swift2

I'm just starting developing apps with Swift 2.0, and as I was writing a function that sends a POST request to a webpage and returns the response of the webpage I'm experiencing a problem with the variable called task, that supposedly sends the request. Earlier today it was working, and I literally change everything as it was before to see if there was anything I did wrong but I couldn't figure it out.

The part that is giving me problems is the following :

```
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request){
        data,response,error in

        if(data == nil){
            print("No response received")
        }

       let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

        if error != nil{
            print("Error=\(error)")
            return
            }
        print("response = \(response)")
        print("responseString = \(responseString)")
        }
```

Which for some reasons always makes the whole thing crashing reporting "(lldb)" in the console.

You can see the rest of the code for the "function" (even if it's not even a function yet) here : http://pastebin.com/DfT6LbCc

If you have any idea why my code is not working, I'd greatly appreciate it if you could let me know!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

In nearly all cases you force-unwrap an optional, you are doing something wrong. Try this:

```
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request){
    (data,response,error) in

    guard let data = data else { print("No response received"); return }

   let responseString = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    if error != nil {
        print("Error=\(error)")
        return
    }
    print("response = \(response)")
    print("responseString = \(responseString)")
}
```